# How to install fuzzy c-means package in anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, cluster-analysis, fuzzy-c-means

I tried `pip install fcmeans` and `pip install f-c-means`, but neither of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

##### Here is what you could do:

1. Install Anaconda and make sure it is working
2. In the folder you are going to be working in, create a file, `environment.yaml`
3. Configure the `environment.yaml` so that it contains the packages you want to work with. See the sample `environment.yaml` below. Note that `fuzzy-c-means` is pip-installed because it doesn't seem that it is currently hosted directly through anaconda channels
4. From a terminal in the directory you will be working with (where the `environment.yaml` is saved), run `conda env create --file environment.yaml`. This will create a new virtual environment containing the packages you want, including `fuzzy-c-means`.
5. Activate the new virtual environment that you created, which was the specified as `name` in the `environment.yaml` using `conda activate my_env_name`. You should note that the name of the environment should appear in the terminal prompt, indicating that the virtual environment is active.
6. If you are using an IDE with some kind of console where you run code, make sure the interpreter is configured to use the new virtual environment that you just created.
7. If you need to make changes to the environment, like add new packages, add them to the `environment.yaml` and then either delete the entire environment and build it from scratch or run `conda env update --file environment.yaml --prune`

##### Sample `environment.yaml` file

```
name: my_env_name
channels:
    - defaults
dependencies:
    - python=3.9
    - jupyter
    - notebook
    - numpy
    - pandas
    - pip
    - pip:
        - fuzzy-c-means
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip install fuzzy-c-means` and it worked for me